# При подключении сайта с ssl сертификатом к серверу nodejs подключение перестает быть защищенным

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl

Может кто знает с чем это связано)
У меня есть сайт с ssl сертификатом,соотвественно он работает на протоколе https и все было ок,но когда мне понадобилось подключить сайт к бд - я перенес все на vps сервер
Сначала сервер написанный на nodejs я открыл на http и увидел,что мой сайт не может приконектиться к сервера,тк разные протоколы..
Открыв сервер на https ,сайт подключился к сервреру,но подключение перестало быть защищенным...

Есть идеи?)

Comment: НЕ проходит проверка сертификата, удостоверяющего центра и т.д. Где браузер пишет ошибку по сертификату? Всмысле какую? На что ругается?

Comment: @SwaD При переходе на сайт, возле ссылки на него написано "подключение к сайту не защищено,не сообщайте этому сайту конфиденциальную инормацию итд"

Comment: А теперь ткни туда и посмотри на данные сертификата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос установив ssl сертификат от letsencrypt на сервер